# Using calibration stack for non PR2 robot

Tags: ros, robot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to calibrate two arm system with sensor head.
Based on PR2 and maxwell calibration stacks i made configs for my system and successfully run the capture_data. But i am unable to get estimation working.
When i run calibration_estimation it crash because of NaN during calculations.

Here is output from estimation node : [estimation_output.txt](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69219006/estimation_output.txt)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32748/using-calibration-stack-for-non-pr2-robot/) by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found answer myself. The problem was caused by baseline_rgbd param in my system.yaml. When this parameter is set to any value, calibration node assume that depth informations is available.

---

Originally posted by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) with karma: 71 on 2012-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1